# Photoshop: How to create a shapes whose anchor points overlap with those of others?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, pen-tool

Using **Photoshop** (and not Illustrator, which I don't have), I would like to get the same result as the one requested in this question: [How can I add shapes to anchor points in illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67042/how-can-i-add-shapes-to-anchor-points-in-illustrator)

Basically, let's say I defined a triangle shape using the pen tool. What I want to do next is creating another triangle shape so that two of its corners overlap with those of the previous triangle. By doing this repeatedly, I shoould be able to achieve my goal.

Is there a way to do that using the pen tool or, if not, what tools related to shapes/paths can I use?

Comment: No, i dont think there is anything that can really make it as easy in PS. Illustrator is just more powerful than PS when it comes to stuff like this.

Comment: Photoshop isn't the right kind of software. No need for Illustrator though, You can do it in Inkscape which is totally free and Open Source. It has an Extension under Generate From Path, called Voronoi Diagram, where you can choose a Delauney Triangulation diagram. All you need is a bunch of circles. [see example](https://imgur.com/35P10k9)